# Tika Error: 500 on processing pdf

Tags: apache-tika

What can possible go wrong in order to get an Error: 500 when I

```
curl -T file.pdf http://localhost:9998/tika > file.txt
```

a Tika server, where file.pdf is on the current directory and Tika is up on localhost:9998 ?

I have tried many different .pdf files to get their extract into .txt form but for most of them I get a 500 Error.

Thanks !

Comment: What gets logged from the Tika server?

Comment: Server just logs "Error: 500". Bypassed the error with
             curl -X PUT --data-binary @file.pdf http://localhost:9998/tika --header "Content-type: application/pdf" > file.txt